# What are DEX and CEX used for?

Tags: exchanges, decentralized-exchange

DEX: Decentralized EXchanges
CEX: Centralized EXchanges

My questions are:

1. what are DEX and CEX used for?
2. how does them work?

Answer (score 0):

OK a DEX is a Decentralized Exchange for Crypto or "Tokens". This means that a person is not required to show id, other than a transaction or funds being what they are, (i.e. confirmations at wallet). You have several DEX's and these are quoted differently on prices as each has it's own value assigned by the trading records that it has for that token. For example when you create a Loan and pay it all at once nothing is needed, and you get paid. Token A is exchanged for Token B and Sold for Token C which is used to pay the loan and return you a profit.

Moving on .....

CEX is a Centralized Exchange, you can think of these as places where seedy people are going to get caught laundering money because they require a policy known as KYC which is KNOW YOUR CUSTOMER, and well, they want to stick a royal microscope right up your life,ask you to trust them with information they can't be held liable for protecting, and well you basically a crypto victim using these but ok, if there's money, and just how many IRS agents will ask questions is always the fun part of looking like a criminal when you want to invest money. On centralized exchanges you can convert to fiat and using the traditional banking system. This allows us to use SWIFT, WIRE, ACH, and others to cash out crypto. Some limit things to crypto exchanges, so not all deal with FIAT, some people don't want to deal with the money just the profit in tokens.

Hopefully your brain has absorbed this! Good Luck!